# linux sh -c replace echo not working

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, profile, sh

This seems like it should have a super simple answer, but I have search for a while and tried different suggestions to no avail.

As an example, I am trying to create a function that will be available when the following is ran

```
sh -c "echo 'test \c'"
```

I have tried adding the following code right after the shebang / first command in both /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc

```
echo () {
    builtin echo -e "$@"
}
```

What is frustrating is that it works in normal sh and bash when logged in. However as soon as sh -c is ran, it just forgets that ever existed. I have tried other tests, like making a function called echo2 and it doesn't exist in sh -c

Now here is the very frustrating thing, it HAS to be sh -c because the proprietary enterprise software application runs its commands inside of sh -c, which I cannot control that... So it HAS to be something that works natively with sh -c "something"

Comment: You'd need to export the function `export -f echo` but `sh` won't pick it up -- function exports are not POSIX. You'll need to implement it as a script.

Comment: Is `sh` a link to bash? On ubuntu it is dash.

Comment: @glennjackman I like the script idea and have already attempted that; however I am using CentOS 7 and echo is immune to that as it is a shell builtin function $man builtin

Comment: @MarkWagner CentOS 7 /bin/sh -> /bin/bash Thanks for the feedback on that

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! I just tried this as sh is actually bash on my system and it worked exactly as you suggested!

Comment: Bash operates differently when invoked as sh - documented in the manual